# Can javascript eval() take variables name and replace them before using

Tags: javascript, jquery, spry

Many thanks for reading ,

Problem context: Use search function of spry in more than one accordion panel.

I am trying to use `eval` (since it is the only way I can think of) to accomplish this simple thing:

```
var ds1 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("ajaxxmllogdaneiz1.php",'root/row]');

var ds2 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("ajaxxmllogdaneiz2.php",'root/row]');

var str1="ds";

var str2= 1;

var result= str1.concat(str2);

//result is now ds1

eval ("result.filter(filterFunc)");
```

I would like `ds1.filter(filterFunc)` to be called but `result.filter(filterFunc)` is called.
Is there a way for `ds1.filter(filterFunc)` to be called with `eval` or alternatives (Jquery?)?
Many thanks 
Dinos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using the value of `result` instead of `"result"` itself, you can do:

`eval (result+".filter(filterFunc)");`

Comment: Many thanks . I have tried combinations but I though eval () would not allow string concatanation inside. Many thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. Note that you can pass **anything** that resolves into a string to `eval()` - be it a concatenation, a `toString()` call, a function call that returns a string, one of the string methods that return a string etc.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using this:

```
eval(result + ".filter(filterFunc)");
```

But you should really consider *not* `eval`ing at all. I don't see why this would ever be advisable. If you must, I would suggest storing the variable to be operated on in a known place. For example:

```
​var Foo = function() {
    return {
        "bar": function() {
            console.log("baz");
        }
    }
};

var foo_list = {};
foo_list["foo"] = Foo();

var part_1 = "fo";
var part_2 = "o";

foo_list[part_1 + part_2].bar();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYGkw/1/)

(You can also store it in `window` this way, but I would advise against that, too.)

Comment: Many thanks  for the proposal and the great elaboration on the subject Waleed.

Answer (score 3):

If the variable you're trying to access are in the global scope, then you can use:

```
var result = 'ds1';

window[result].filter(filterFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use eval for anything less than executing completely arbitrary code.

You may want to store the `XMLDataSet`s in an array.

```
var datasets = [];
for (var n=1; n<=2; n++) {
    datasets.push(new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("ajaxxmllogdaneiz" + n + ".php", "root/row"));
}

for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) {
    var ds = datasets[i];
    ds.filter(filterFunc);
}
```